# Не совпадают выходные данные в парсере на Python, почему?

Tags: python-3.x, for, print

```
import bs4
import time
import csv
from selenium import webdriver  # pip install selenium
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager  # pip install webdriver-manager

with webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())) as driver:  # Открываем хром
    driver.get(
        "https://www.vseinstrumenti.ru/search/page3/?what=%D0%9C%D1%83%D1%84%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%92%D0%A0%2020%2a%203%2F4%20Valfex%20%28100%2F25%29")  # Открываем страницу
    time.sleep(5)  # Время на прогрузку страницы
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    heads = soup.find_all('div', class_='pSmTBa AUnCMw YJsT8J UKF+8w Z-t4Xt')
    # print(len(heads))
    for i in heads:
        w = i.find_next('div', class_='j07RMn wyyij7').find('a').get('href')
        # print('https://www.vseinstrumenti.ru'+w)
        url = ('https://www.vseinstrumenti.ru' + w)

    with webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())) as loom:  # Открываем хром
        loom.get(url)  # Открываем страницу
        time.sleep(5)  # Время на прогрузку страницы
        head = bs4.BeautifulSoup(loom.page_source, 'html.parser')
        zagol = head.find('h1', class_='typography heading v3 -no-margin')
        print(zagol.text.strip())
        nazvan = (zagol.text.strip())
        param_1 = head.find('div', class_='IjwckR').find_all('span', itemprop='name')
        for ex in param_1:
            print(ex.text.strip())
            name = (ex.text.strip())
        param_2 = head.find('div', class_='IjwckR').find_all('span', itemprop='value')
        for wee in param_2:
            print(wee.text.strip())
            charact = (wee.text.strip())

            print(name + ':' + charact)
```

Есть код парсера который собирает данные. В итерации for ex in param_1: данные на печать выводятся правильно , последовательно. В итерации for wee in param_2: тоже на печать всё правильно выводится последовательно. Но в print(name + ':' + charact) параметр name повторяется одно и то-же, тогда как в параметре charact данные выводятся правильно. Кто знает в чем причина (ошибка)?

Comment: name как я понимаю должен меняться при конкотенации print(name + ':' + charact). Что характерно charact меняется, а name нет при выводе не печать.

Answer (score 0):

```
# 1
param_1 = head.find('div', class_='IjwckR').find_all('span', itemprop='name')
# for ex in param_1:
#     print(ex.text.strip())
#     name = (ex.text.strip())
param_2 = head.find('div', class_='IjwckR').find_all('span', itemprop='value')
# for wee in param_2:
#     print(wee.text.strip())
#     charact = (wee.text.strip())

for x, y in zip(param_1, param_2):
    name = x.text.strip()
    charact = y.text.strip()
    print(name + ':' + charact)

#2
par = head.find_all(attrs={"data-qa": "specification-item"})
for x in par:
    name = x.find('span', itemprop='name').text.strip()
    charact = x.find('span', itemprop='value').text.strip()
    print(name, charact)
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Огромное вам спасибо!!!